# Flutter - Image.network - HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Image.network to load images from internet.

Even I'm using `errorBuilder` it is throwing me an exception.

How to fix this?

Here's a sample code.

```
class Test1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const Test2(),
                ));
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: Image.network(
                'https://logo.clearbit.com/tmall.com',
                errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Something wrong!',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine and no exceptions until I navigated to **Test2**...

After navigated I'm getting an exception.

Here it is.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://logo.clearbit.com/tmall.com

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:97:9)
<asynchronous suspension>

Image provider: NetworkImage("https://logo.clearbit.com/tmall.com", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://logo.clearbit.com/tmall.com", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

How do I get rid of this?

And also I used **cached_network_image** it is also same.

---

Per comments below:

> I used errorBuilder if the image url is not exist then show something.
> My problem is it is showing at the first appearance with no errors (image displays) and
> after I navigated throwing an exception (HTTP 404).

Comment: Q: How do I get rid of HTTP 404?  A: [HTTP 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) means "page or file not found".  The FIRST thing to do is to double-check your URL.  Is it valid?  Does the page and/or file actually exist?

Comment: Yeah. I used `errorBuilder` if the image url is not exist then show something. My problem is it is showing at the first appearance with no errors and after I navigated throwing an exception.

Comment: check your image URL is it working?

Comment: No it's not working. I'm getting these data from api. So I need to show some text if the url in not valid or not exist

Comment: SUGGESTION:  ISOLATE THE PROBLEM. 1) see if you can reproduce the problem with a local, static image (or equivalent). 2) If it works, then your Flutter/Dart code is OK; the problem is with "https://logo.clearbit.com/tmall.com".  Troubleshoot from there.

Comment: No no. Whatever link I put there. i. e. Invalid url. Same thing happens.

Comment: https://logo.clearbit.com/tmall.com  the image url is invalid thats why u are getting error. actually image was not found as the url is not valid. You can use below url to test url implementation https://diamu.com.bd/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Germany-Home-Jersey-World-Cup-2022-2.jpg